# intenal server error with .htacces file

Tags: .htaccess

i need your help  please, because of  .htacces file,  when i put it on the server  i get the Internal Server Error  and when i delet it i can see the website onligne, but  with  may problems of links,  title of links become links  .html  and of course after following it  page not found ( normal because, the real link it's  mysite/offers.php?id=

and this is a copy of .htacces :

```
IndexIgnore  */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

php_value post_max_size 96M

php_value upload_max_filesize 96M

php_value max_execution_time 0

php_value memory_limit 96M

# Changement d'extension

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

<Limit GET POST>

order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from all

</Limit>

<Limit PUT DELETE>

order deny,allow

deny from all

</Limit>

AuthName mysite.com

AuthUserFile /home/larbi/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd

AuthGroupFile /home/larbi/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*)-.*$   offres.php?lang=$2&id=2_$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^prestations.php$   offres.php?id=2_1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) /erreur_404.html
```

waiitng youe answer please, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your htaccess file but make sure of these things:

1. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled. It should be a line in httpd.conf that looks something like:

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```
2. Make sure there's a file `/erreur_404.html` that exists, if that file is missing, the rewrite engine will loop.
3. Additionally, make sure `/offres.php` exists, if that file is is missing, the rewrite engine will redirect to `/erreur_404.html`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are right i don't see mod_rewrite how can  i make it please thank you

Comment: @larbi It depends, find your system in [this list and try one of these](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=how+to+enable+mod_rewrite+apache2&oq=how+to+enable+mod_rewrite)